# Cannot boot to alternate Windows partition - black screen

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I have a machine, with Hyper-V server on it.

The idea was that it would run a single Windows 10 VM (which I would use for my day to day).

I switched to booting the VHDX for that VM straight from the Windows boot manager, bypassing Hyper-V.

All is well.

Now, Windows refuses to do its upgrade from 1909, to 2004, because it's being run via this native boot to VHD mechanism.

So, I want to convert this system back to a physical drive, to remove that complication (wasn't getting the key benefit of running off a VHDX anyway),  and avoid this problem in future.

So, I:

- created a new partition on another internal drive
- cloned an image of the VHDX, onto that partition (using Macrium - I think this uses VSS under the covers)

So I now have this other partition, which appears to be a perfect copy of my VHDX (but as a regular NTFS partition). I can see all the files there, the total size matches well with VM's c:

I hit msconfig, and added a new boot option:

```
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {00af6094-8fd3-11ea-8d75-dd9ab7a724e4}
device                  partition=I:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             sys3
locale                  en-US
osdevice                partition=I:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {486b6b92-cad2-11ea-b801-806e6f6e6963}
safeboot                Minimal
vga                     Yes
quietboot               Yes
bootlog                 Yes
sos                     Yes
```

However, when I choose this option at boot, I get a black screen, and a reboot.  Absolutely nothing else, despite all the diagnostic options set. No info at all.

It feels like the Windows boot manager is perhaps unable to see this new partition, but I cannot see why not?

The disk housing the partition is MBR.  This new partition is extended, not marked as active (on same disk, another partition houses Hyper-V server).

Appreciate any insight. Did I miss a step?

Comment: Is the black screen at start of the boot process or when switching to GUI mode ?

Comment: After choosing that OS option, it flickers slightly, but really it's only black from there on. Don't get any glimpse of anything that looks like Windows. It does take a while to fail and reboot though -  I think around 15 or 20s.

Comment: 15 - 20s may be when it switches to GUI. Power it off before that. It should start in recovery mode after 3 tries.